# $N$ balls either green or yellow into $k$ bins

Tags: combinatorics

$N$ balls are given (unlabelled). There'll be $a$ number of green balls, and $b$ number of yellow balls. We are to put them in $k$ labelled bins.

a) How many ways are there to put these $N$ balls into k bins?

$${a+k-1 \choose k-1}{b+k-1\choose k-1}$$

This is what I got by using the Weak Composition.

b) If those $N$ balls weren't colorred and we have to color them before putting them into $k$ bins, how many possible ways are there?

I divided k bins into $2k$ subbins so that each subbin contains only one color. So I get

$${N+2k-1 \choose 2k-1}$$

However I am not sure if I got this correct.

c) Now the question is that I have to relate the answers for a) and b).

Since $b = N-a$. Then we have

$${a+k-1 \choose k-1}{b+k-1 \choose k-1}={a+k-1 \choose k-1}{N-a+k-1 \choose k-1}$$

And I just assume the following is correct:

$${N+2k-1 \choose 2k-1}={a+k-1 \choose k-1}{N-a+k-1 \choose k-1}$$

But to be honest, I don't know. Can somebody help? Thank you so much

Comment: Your answer to part (a) looks good. However, it's not exactly clear to me what you're asking in part (b). Could you clarify?